# rosnode list for not active nodes

Tags: ros, nodes

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm creating something like an IDE for ROS. Is it possible to get a list of all available nodes. Something like 'rosnode list' but for the not yet started nodes.
I think 'rosrun TAB TAB ' displays them, but this needs manual input of the TAB-key. Maybe there is a way to use the autocompletion-feature in a shellscript.

Thanks for the help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10130/rosnode-list-for-not-active-nodes/) by [Filip](https://answers.ros.org/users/633/filip/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2011-05-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could probably use the completion to make a rospack list-nodes or similar.
Maybe the output of rospack list (only packages) can help you.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Filip](https://answers.ros.org/users/633/filip/) on 2011-06-01**:
Well I guess rospack list-names will do it at the moment. Thank you very much.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-03-31**:
Groovy bash completion uses  catkin_find --without-underlays --libexec  to determine the dir for executables of package PKG.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll find the tab-completion code in /opt/ros/diamondback/ros/tools/rosbash/rosbash

Look for `function _roscomplete_exe`

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-05-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Filip](https://answers.ros.org/users/633/filip/) on 2011-06-01**:
Thanks, I tried it a while, but couldn't figure out how this works. I guess this would be a nice solution.